# scoping in Durandal viewmodel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, durandal

In one of my viewmodels I have a function `Control` that creates an objects later to be bound to the view:

(The code is only reproducing my viewmodel, therefore it may be incomplete or containing some mistakes. If you need more details please ask in a comment bellow. Since the example refers to durandaljs framework I cannot provide a JsFiddle.)

```
function Control ( value ) {
    var self = this;
    self.param = value;
    self.param1 = ko.observable(value.text());
    self.param2 = ko.computed(function() {
        read: function(){
            return getString(self.param.text()).StringValue();
        },
        write: function(newValue){
            stringsArray.push(
                {StringID: ko.observable(-1), StringValue: ko.observable(newValue)});
            self.param.text(-1);
        },
        owner: self
    });
    self.param3 = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.param2() + ' something_else';
    });
    self.param1.subscribe(function( newValue ) {
        if ( newValue ) {
            self.param3(newValue + 'text');
        }
    });

}

var controls = ko.observableArray([
    new Control({id: 1, text: ko.observable(2)}),
    new Control({id: 2, text: ko.observable(4)}),
    new Control({id: 2, text: ko.observable(1)})
]);

var stringsArray = ko.observableArray([
    {StringID: ko.observable(1), StringValue: ko.observable('aaa')},
    {StringID: ko.observable(2), StringValue: ko.observable('bbb')}
    {StringID: ko.observable(3), StringValue: ko.observable('ccc')}
    {StringID: ko.observable(4), StringValue: ko.observable('ddd')}
    {StringID: ko.observable(5), StringValue: ko.observable('eee')}
    {StringID: ko.observable(6), StringValue: ko.observable('fff')}
]); // data retrieved from the database

var deactivate = function() {
    controls.removeAll();
    stringsArray.removeAll();
};

var vm = {
    deactivate: deactivate,
    controls: controls,
    stringsArray: stringsArray
};
return vm;

function getString ( stringID ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < stringsArray().length; i++ ) {
        if ( stringsArray()[i].StringID() === stringID ) {
            return stringsArray()[i];
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

My problem is that the objects that are created from the function are scoped globally, therefore when I deactivate the viewmodel they still exist in memory.

How should I rewrite the `function Control(value)` so the objects that it creates will have the viewmodel scope. They will only exist when the viewmodel is active and discarded when I remove them from the observableArray in the `deactivate` method?

Comment: check if you've turned on cacheViews: true. The vm is returning a singleton, so with cacheViews: true the view will never be removed.

Comment: I tried adding `cacheViews: false`, but it is still the same behaviour. The problem is scoping the object that is created in the `function Control()`. Right now the scope of the object created is global. I don't know how could I rewrite the function so the scope of the objects would only be the viewmodel.

Comment: Can you fork the example below and reproduce that behavior?

Comment: It is very strange. I put a `console.log(this)` just in the beginning of the function Control and it printed an object `Control {}`. I put it in the end of the function as well and it returned the global object `Window {...}`.

Comment: http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#extras/scope (https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0/blob/gh-pages/app/extras/scope/index.js) is using the original code from above, but I don't see anything hanging out on global. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: I can't. The computed is still throwing me an error that it doesn't find anything in the strings array after I re-navigate to the vm.

Comment: move `stringsArray` before `controls`. `stringsArray` is undefined when you make calls to new Control() so that fails.

Comment: No. `StringsArray` is not undefined. When I re-navigate to the view I construct a control with different proprieties and I retrieve different strings. It's not the new computed that I create throwing me the error but the one that I created the previous time I was on the page. Is there a chance that knockout may not dispose the computeds since it is dependant on the `stringsArray` and the strings array still is in the memory?

Comment: I forgot to say that I removed the `stringsArray.removeAll();` from the `deactivate` method to be able to navigate away from the vm. Otherwise the computed was throwing the error when the deactivate method was called.

Comment: Re: ` find anything in strings array after I re-navigate ` that's expected. In `deactivate` there's  a call to `stringsArray.removeAll()`. Please come back once you've an example that works and shows the issue that your seeing. At the moment there are too many moving parts.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. By explicitly disposing the computed in the deactivate function `for(var i=0;i<controls.peek().lenght;i++) {controls.peek()[i].param3.dispose(); controls.peek()[i].param3.dispose();}` I don't have the problem any more. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Excellent. Can you please add an answer and mark as accepted after a couple of days. That way the question can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my problem was that the `ko.computed` contained by the object. The computed was not dropped when I was deactivating the viewmodel, because some external data, that they were dependent on, was still in the memory.

I found about it in this post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knockoutjs/4HV_PgcBNXA/ozoyXlygJHwJ

After disposing manually the `ko.computed` in the deactivate function the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting example, but I'm not sure if the code above truly reflects what you're doing or if it's a copy/paste issue.

I brought up a dFiddle at http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#extras/scope in order to debug it. Feel free to fork and modify.

Currently when you move away from the view Durandal's live cycle event `deactivate` is triggered which will `removeAll` entries from `stringArray` and `controls`, but of course leave the knockout observableArrays in memory at least if the view model returns a singleton and cacheViews is set to true.

I'd most probably convert the vm into a constructor function and while on it move the control into it's own module, but of course without knowing the exact requirements that's just a gut feeling.

Something along the following should get you started:

### view model

```
define(['durandal/system', 'jquery', 'knockout', './control'], function( system, $, ko, Control ) {
    "use strict";

    var vm = function() {
        this.controls = ko.observableArray([
            new Control('value1'),
            new Control('value2'),
            new Control('value2')
        ]);
    };

    vm.prototype.deactivate = function() {
        this.controls.removeAll();
    };

    return vm;
});
```

### control module

```
define(['knockout'], function(  ko ) {
    "use strict";

    function Control ( value ) {
        this.param = value;
        this.param1 = ko.observable(value.text);
        this.param2 = ko.computed(function() {
            //translate self.param.StringID with data from another
            //an observableArray containing data retrieved from the server
            //return getString(this.param.StringID()).StringValue();
            return 'Computed' + this.param.id;
        // ko.computed takes a context parameter
        }, this);
        this.param3 = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.param2() + 'something_else';
        }, this);
        this.param1.subscribe(function( newValue ) {
            if ( newValue ) {
                this.param3(newValue + 'text');
            }
        });
    }

    var stringsArray = ko.observableArray([]); // data retrieved from the database

    return Control;

    function getString ( stringID ) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < stringsArray().length; i++ ) {
            if ( stringsArray()[i].StringID === stringID ) {
                return stringsArray()[i];
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }

});
```

Live version available at http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#extras/scope/ctor